Confusion with SEC filling tags of operating cash flow
I try to scrape fundamentals from the oficial SEC homepage for example for AAPL (url: https://data.sec.gov/api/xbrl/companyfacts/CIK0000320193.json). I noticed that in the time series for 'NetCashProvidedByUsedInOperatingActivities' some quarters are missing, e.g. 2014-03-31. I figured out that this quarter is however included in the time series for 'NetCashProvidedByUsedInInvestingActivitiesContinuingOperations'. How could this be possible? I mean, it is of course possible that a company completely changes its business and therefore the continuing cash flow is 0, but even after thinking about it for a long time, I can't think of any reason for the opposite.
Another reason could of course be that missing values do not actually mean that the value is equal to zero but just missing. But this doesn't make sense either, because I can rule out data errors in the submitted reporting due to the enormous size of Apple and as far as I know, stock companies of that size are obliged to report their cash flow statements every single quarter.
Could anyone help me clear up this confusion? Many thanks in advance
